# jQuery first-child not selecting or is selecting itself

Tags: jquery, css

Why is :firstChild being ignored? The class is being added to the parent selector, not the child:

```js
$('#foo:first-child').addClass('foobar');
```

```css
.foobar {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's working... https://jsfiddle.net/cphk3bLs/
maybe declare the `foobar` class?

Comment: it's adding the div with id 'foo', not the child which has id 'bar'...

Comment: Ok so I need $('#foo #bar').first()? stuggling to understand how firstChild would ever be benficial

Comment: Since only one element can have a given ID, `$('#bar').first()` is logically redundant. It looks for elements with ID that are the first in the document, not for a child _of the ID_. You'd need `$('#bar *').first()`.

Comment: About `first-child` use and all the others. https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048t#toc-ez0b-x-y 

Comment: If I understand the question correctly then you're missing a space between the two selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand how `:first-child` works. It's not a descendant selector. It's a modifier on the current selector. In other words, it looks for *elements with ID which are also the first child of their parent element*.

If you want the first child *inside* `#foo`, add a space to indicate a descendant relationship. This then modifies the *any element* selector that's implied by the empty value, equivalent to `*:first-child`.

Note that this is essentially a CSS thing. You can make it a jQuery thing by using `.first()`, as you suggested in a comment. That doesn't change the important points, though--you still need a descendant/child selector.

```js
$('#foo :first-child').addClass('foobar');
```

```css
.foobar {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```